# Use Grapgics without button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010

i have a form where i illustrate a pie chart for the percentage of three types of assembly commands (R, I, J). To do that i'm using graphics library. My application until now shows the chart and the percent foreach command after a button is clicked. What i need is to do that without clicking on a button. I tried some alternatives but nothing came up. Only the percentages show up and the pie chart is not showing up until i press the button. Some of my initial code that works with button_click but also pictures of my form are shown below. 
any help pls??

```
    public float d1;
    public float d2;
    public float d3;

 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SolidBrush b1 = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue);
        SolidBrush b2 = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
        SolidBrush b3 = new SolidBrush(Color.LawnGreen);
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(60, 10, 200, 200);
        Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black);

        graphics.DrawPie(p, rect, 0, d1);
        graphics.FillPie(b1, rect, 0, d1);
        graphics.DrawPie(p, rect, d1, d2);
        graphics.FillPie(b2, rect, d1, d2);
        graphics.DrawPie(p, rect, d1 + d2, d3);
        graphics.FillPie(b3, rect, d1 + d2, d3);
        comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;

        label1.Text = "R_type   (" + (d1 * 100 / 360).ToString() + "%)";
        label2.Text = "I_type   (" + (d2 * 100 / 360).ToString() + "%)";
        label3.Text = "J_type   (" + (d3 * 100 / 360).ToString() + "%)";
    }
```

[image]

When i tried to copy the code included to the Button1_click() method to a new void method, only the panel with the percentages was shown but the chart not. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Following is a snippet where i get a graphics object in my own code :

```
Graphics g = CreateGraphics();
short margin = global::FrakoPlanner.NET.Properties.Settings.Default.Margin;
                cellHeight = Convert.ToInt32(g.MeasureString("Font", this.TextFont).Height) + margin;
g.Dispose();
```

the point is that you need to create a graphics object if you want to draw in a button click handler.

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost certain you're not aware of your actual problem.

The problem isn't the fact that it works only from within the button's event handler.
That is a geographical (inside the handler) differentiator which is unimportant.

The problem is the time when you execute those drawing operations.

I'm presuming that "outside the button's event handler" means inside a place (maybe the Form's constructor) which gets called before it is even possible to render.

**Easy-way-out Answer** (which does not include any insights)

- Just add a Timer component to your form
- create an event handler to its `Tick` event
- set its `Enabled` property to `true`
- set its `Interval` property to .. say 200 (meaning milliseconds)
- write your drawing code inside the event handler created at step 2
- programmatically disable the timer inside the event Handler (either at the top or at the bottom of the event handler)

**Healthy solution**

- Read about creating Custom controls (not User controls).
- Create a CustomControl and call it MyPieRenderer